# Cannot use process.env in React component, but can import it in webpack.config.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

My React app is not built using 'create-react-app'.

I am able to console.log from webpack.config.js the process environments i have imported and parsed from a .env file using dotenv library.

However, 'npm run build' fails. When i substitute the variable with the URL string, 'npm run build' passes.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: 'config/docker/production/.env'});

// call dotenv and it will return an Object with a parsed key 
const env = dotenv.parsed;

// reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
return prev;
}, {});

console.log(process.env.API_URL); -> prints out http://localhost:5000/api/something

const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/static/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/static/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            path: __dirname + '/static/dist',
            filename: 'styles.css',
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production -p --progress --config webpack.config.js"
  }
```

**config/docker/production/.env**

```
API_URL=http://]ocalhost:5000/api/something
```

**MyComp.jsx**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

class MyComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      races: []};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch({process.env.API_URL}) -> FAILS
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/something') -> PASSES
      .then(results => results.json()) 
      .then(data => this.setState({ races: data.data }));

  }

  render() {
      ...
  }
}

export default MyComp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop 'process.env' from line 10 in your webpack config file

```
prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
```

to

```
prev[`${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
```

and use the 'API_URL' variable directly without process.env.

you can read webpack documentation of DefinePlugin [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

another issue might be how you are using 'process.env.API_URL'. 
it should be:

```
fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}`)
```

see the tick and dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) webpack plugin to expose environment variables to your `React` application.

**Installation:**

```
npm i -D dotenv-webpack
```

**Usage:**

```
// webpack.config.js

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: 'config/docker/production/.env',
    }),
  ]
  ...
};
```